# Based in selected JSON object Display tis value Using Jquery

Tags: jquery, json

On selecting JSON object from dropdown list the values releted to that object should display in body or textbox.

Here is my JSON demo:

```
         {  
    "EmployeeDetails":[  
      {  
         "EmpID":1,
         "EmpName":"xyz",
         "EmpPhn":231
      },
      {  
         "EmpID":1,
         "EmpName":"xyz",
         "EmpPhn":231
      }
    ],
    "jobDetails":{  
      "JobID":1,
      "JobName":"opqr"
    },
    "DeptDetails":{  
      "deptID":1,
      "deptname":"qtrye",
      "deptloc":"xbnz"
      } 
    }
```

Example if I select "JobDetails" from droplist then i should display

```
     JobID: 1 
     JobName: opqr
```

in  body content.

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle?

Comment: Here is code for selection http://jsfiddle.net/TY76W/23/

Comment: Sorry Bro, Im new in jsfiddle so im not aware how to add the data.json file in that.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/TY76W/24/

Comment: Thanks Mohit Arora, its coming Perfect.

Comment: Thanks Mohit, Could you tell me how remove double qoutes , curly braces and squre bracket from the genrated result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `select` element with `option`s, which values are the `keys` of your JSON data. Then on `change` event, display the value of the specified key.

I have implemented the mentioned solution:

**HTML**

```
<select id="dropdown">
    <option value="EmployeeDetails">Employee Details</option>
    <option value="jobDetails">Job Details</option>
    <option value="DeptDetails">Dept Details</option>
</select>

<pre id="objView"></pre>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var json = {
    "EmployeeDetails": [{
        "EmpID": 1,
        "EmpName": "xyz",
        "EmpPhn": 231
    }, {
        "EmpID": 1,
        "EmpName": "xyz",
        "EmpPhn": 231
    }],
        "jobDetails": {
        "JobID": 1,
            "JobName": "opqr"
    },
        "DeptDetails": {
        "deptID": 1,
        "deptname": "qtrye",
        "deptloc": "xbnz"
    }
};

var $dropdown = $('#dropdown'),
    $objView = $('#objView');

$dropdown.on('change', function() {
    $objView.html(JSON.stringify(json[$dropdown.val()]));
});

$dropdown.trigger('change');
```

And here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/07fgpw9e/).

*Note:* I print the plain object in `pre` tag. You can prettify and do whatever you need before outputing in HTML.

**UPDATE**

I have updated the solution. Instead of having a static HTML, I have generated the `option`s from the JSON. Here it is:

**HTML**

```
<select id="dropdown">
</select>

<pre id="objView"></pre>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var $dropdown = $('#dropdown'),
$objView = $('#objView'),
$docFragment = $(document.createDocumentFragment());

var json = {
    "EmployeeDetails": [{
        "EmpID": 1,
        "EmpName": "xyz",
        "EmpPhn": 231
    }, {
        "EmpID": 1,
        "EmpName": "xyz",
        "EmpPhn": 231
    }],
        "jobDetails": {
        "JobID": 1,
            "JobName": "opqr"
    },
        "DeptDetails": {
        "deptID": 1,
        "deptname": "qtrye",
        "deptloc": "xbnz"
    }
};

for (var prop in json) {
    $('<option/>', {
        val: prop,
        text: prop
    }).appendTo($docFragment);
}

$dropdown.append($docFragment);

$dropdown.on('change', function() {
    $objView.html(JSON.stringify(json[$dropdown.val()]));
});

$dropdown.trigger('change');
```

[JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/07fgpw9e/2/)

**UPDATE 2** (regarding your comment)

Probably you have a few options here.

1.You can implement a function, which will take the object, iterate over the properties and nicely print them.

2.You can do the above using MV* framework, such as AngularJS. You just bind the model, set some value (e.g. object) and it will take care the iterating and related things for you. Finally, it will print the object in any *form* you like.

3.Finally, if you don't want to iterate over the properties or use a framework, you can simply remove the unwanted characters from the string. For example, this is code for removing curly/square brackets, double quotes as well as replacing the commas with new line:

```
$dropdown.on('change', function() {
    var objString = JSON.stringify(json[$dropdown.val()]);

    objString = objString.replace(/[\{\}\[\]\"]*/ig, '');    // Remove unwanted chars
    objString = objString.replace(/\,/ig, '<br/>');         // Replace commas with new lines (i.e. br tags)

    $objView.html(objString);
});
```

[JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/07fgpw9e/5/)

Comment: Thanks Karlen ,  iam using a data.json file which contains huge JSON object . For Every Json Object i cannot use <option> in <select>

Comment: Thanks Karlen Kishmiryan

Comment: Could you tell me how remove double qoutes , curly braces and squre bracket from the genrated result

Comment: Thanks Karlen Kishmiryan, Best Regards

Comment: Hi, Its was working fine before 2 hour ago but now an error is throwing in     " $objView.html(JSON.stringify($dropdown.val()])); " specifying "jquery 0x800a1391 - javascript runtime error 'json' is undefined" when i execute in IE9. Could you help me out with these issue.

Comment: Hope this helps: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/fc41127c-0243-4d2e-8e7c-2b311f12e390/ie9-json-not-defined